# HTML if else condition for printing items in list

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm making a website with flask, and I pass in a list. My .html file has this code:

```
{$ for file in list %}
 <div> 
 <img ... > </img>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now if list.length == 0 I want it to just do something like

```
<h2> Error </h2>
```

instead. How do I make an if statement to check if the list is empty, and if it is then I print error on the website, if it is not, I print the images in the list. I tried to put:

```
<script>
 if(list.length==0){
<h2>Error</h2>
}
else{
"the for loop stuff"
}
</script>
```

but this does not work.
THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flask with Jinja2 as a template engine, the **if-else** syntax requires you to write the following statement

```html
{% if mylist.length == 0 %}
    <div>error</div>
{% else %}
    <!-- loop -->
{% endif %}
```

**Note**: Since `list` is a Python **keyword** i suggest you to use another name for your list in order to avoid possible conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

In this [pythonprogramming page about flask 7](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/flask-7-the-if-condition/), you will find some example code and a video. The example shows an if-else statement:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h3> {{ post.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
 
    {% if author %}
    <span style="font-size:0.5em;color:yellowgreen">{{ post.author }} </span>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if date %}
    <span style="font-size:0.5em;color:yellowgreen">{{ post.date }}</span>
    {% endif %}
 
{% endfor %}
```

I decided to post my answer to share this learning resource because I have noted that the example does not use any `<script>` tag (not sure if it helps).

The comparison operator is almost the same everywhere as you can see in both the [Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_comparison_operators.asp) and [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#comparisons) references.

Therefore, the equivalent for your code would be:

```
{% if list.length == 0 %}
...
{% endif %}
```